# How to set margin in tabbar Xamarin forms IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin forms and creating tabbed page. In IOS I want to increase height of tabbar, so display some space at bottom of tab title. How can I set this?

I have tried following code but didn't work. Any other way to set margin at bottom? :

```
public class BottomTabbedPage : TabbedRenderer
{
    private readonly float tabBarHeight = 72f;
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        TabBar.UnselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(208,208,208);
        TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y + (TabBar.Frame.Height - tabBarHeight), TabBar.Frame.Width, tabBarHeight);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the code below in the event `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()`:

```
private readonly float tabBarHeight = 72f;

public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

    CGRect tabFrame = TabBar.Frame;
    tabFrame.Height = tabBarHeight;
    tabFrame.Y = View.Frame.Height - tabBarHeight;

    TabBar.Frame = tabFrame;          
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to adjust the position of icon and title, use this:

```
foreach (UIViewController vc in ViewControllers)
{
    //Adjust the title's position   
    vc.TabBarItem.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(0, -36);
    //Adjust the icon's position
    vc.TabBarItem.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(-36, 0, 36, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works fine, But I want to add margin at bottom because Title of page display touch to touch to screen display. Any idea about that?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Please check my update, use the code above to adjust that.